# Youtube encoder won't start for live streams

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm trying to get a livestream working on youtube. I want to stream 360° content with H264 video and AAC audio. The stream is started with the youtube live api from my mobile app and librtmp is used to deliver video and audio packets. I easily get to the point where the livestream health is good and my broadcast and stream are bound successfully.

However, when I try to transition to "`testing`" like this:

```js
YoutubeManager.this.youtube.liveBroadcasts().transition("testing", liveBroadcast.getId(), "status").execute();
```

I get stuck on the "`startTesting`" status every time (100% reproducible) while I expect it to change to testing after few seconds to allow me to change it to live.

I don't know what's going on as in the youtube live control room everything seems to be fine but the encoder won't start.

Is it a common issue? Is there a mean to access the encoder logs? If you need more information feel free to ask me.

Regards.

Comment: You can test the solution provided in [this thread](https://mavicpilots.com/threads/livestreaming-with-youtube-getting-stuck-at-start-encoder.7502/). The YouTube streaming option creates a new live event but if you want the live stream to just start on your main youtube channel, use custom RTMP URL, which is rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/YOUR_KEY. Works much more seamlessly!

Comment: The stream on my channel in "stream now" worked! It helped me founding out how to fix the streams in the event!
Streaming on my channel only wasn't a solution for me as I'm sending a 360° video stream which wasn't displayed in the according format there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary fix !

I noticed 2 things :

- When the autostart option was on, the stream changed its state to startLive as soon as I stopped sending data. It suggested that the encoder was trying to start but it was too slow to do it before some other data paket was received (I guess)
- When I tried to stream to the "Stream now" URL, as @noogui suggested, it worked ! So I checked out what was the difference in the stream now & event configurations.

It turned out I just had to activate the low latency option as it's done by default in the stream now configuration.

I consider it as a temporary fix because I don't really know why the encoder isn't starting otherwise and because it doesn't work with the autostart option... So I hope it wont break again if Youtube does another change on their encoder.

So, if you have to work with the Youtube api, good luck guys !